# Related Rates: Moving Kite

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, related-rates

> A kite 75 feet above the ground moves horizontally at a speed 4 ft/s. At what rate is the angle $\theta$, which is between the string and the horizontal ray, decreasing when 250 feet of string has been let out?

I discovered the answer is $\cfrac{d\theta}{dt}=-\cfrac{3}{625}$ radians per second. Initially I tried solving it using $\cos\theta=\cfrac{4t}{250}$, differentiating both sides to solve for $\cfrac{d\theta}{dt}$, but I got the wrong answer. It turns out I needed to implicitly differentiate $\cot\theta=\cfrac{4t}{75}$. Can anyone explain why this particular trig function is necessary? I understand generally it's crucial to pick the right trig function because you're usually solving for a value of a particular side of a right triangle, but in this case I figured as long as I pull out $\cfrac{d\theta}{dt}$ and isolate it then I should get the right answer regardless of the function I use. But that wasn't the case.

Any answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Kite flying diagram]

The problem is not with which trig function you picked since it should always work properly, i.e., you get the same answer, regardless of which function you use. Instead, the problem is that the $250$ is *not* a constant. Instead, consider the diagram above, where $A$ is the person's position and $C$ is where the kite is located, so $\left|AC\right|$ is the length of the string currently let out. Using the Pythagorean theorem gives that in general

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left|AC\right| & = \sqrt{(4t)^2 + 75^2} \\
& = \sqrt{16t^2 + 5625}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This means $\left|AC\right| = 250$ is the length of the string that is let out *only* at a certain time, in particular at $4t = \sqrt{250^2 - 75^2} \implies t \approx 59.62$ seconds.

Using that $\cos \theta$ is the adjacent side length divided by hypotenuse gives, from \eqref{eq1A}, that the correct expression using $\cos$ would instead be

$$\cos \theta = \frac{4t}{\sqrt{16t^2 + 5625}} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

I'll leave it to you to differentiate and solve this yourself to confirm that you then get the same result as you got using $\cot \theta = \frac{4t}{75}$.

Comment: I find that I can only solve this and get the correct answer if $\sin\theta=\cfrac{75}{250}$. But shouldn't that, too, be a problem since 250 is a constant here when it shouldn't be?

Comment: @Lex_i Note the correct expression for $\sin \theta$ is actually $\sin \theta = \frac{75}{\sqrt{16t^2 + 5625}}$. This value will vary for different values of $t$, in particular it'll be larger for smaller values of $t$ and smaller for larger values of $t$. It's *only* at one specific value of $t$, where as I show above is $t \approx 59.62$ seconds, where $\sin \theta = \frac{75}{250}$. When you differentiate $\cot \theta = \frac{4t}{75}$, you get $\left(\frac{-1}{\sin^2 \theta}\right)\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{4}{75}$. This is true for *all* values of $t$. In particular, note that ...

Comment: @Lex_i (cont.) $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ *varies* with $t$. The question wants to know what it's value is at the specific $t$ where the length of the string, i.e., hypotenuse of the triangle, is $250$. At that specific point *only*, you have the value of $\sin \theta = \frac{75}{250}$ that you can substitute, as you did, to get your correct result of $\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt} = -\frac{3}{625}$. I used $\theta(t)$ to emphasize that the angle, and thus its derivative, depends on the time $t$. At other values of $t$, the value of $\sin \theta$ would be different, as well as $\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}$.

Comment: That clears everything up now, thank you

Comment: @Lex_i You're welcome. FYI, for anybody else reading this, I've now also added & used a diagram to help explain it. I'm sorry I didn't do that earlier as it might have helped you somewhat with understanding.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It isn't necessary to work with the cotangent function in particular.  Its use is suggested in the given solution only as a matter of convenience.   We have a rate at which the horizontal position, rendered as a distance from the point directly over the kite-flyer, is increasing, $ \ \frac{dH}{dt} \ = \ +4 \ $ ft./sec. , so we will want to work with a trigonometric function of $ \ \theta \ $ that involves $ \ H \   $  in some way.  While $ \ \cos \theta \ = \ \frac{H}{L} \ \ , $ is a reasonable choice, one that uses the *constant* altitude will be less troublesome, such as $ \ \tan \theta \ = \ \frac{75}{H} \ \ . $

Upon rearranging this equation to eliminate the ratio, we can then differentiate implicitly to obtain
$$ H · \tan \theta \ \ = \ \ 75 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d}{dt} \ [ \ H · \tan \theta \ ] \ \ = \ \ \frac{d}{dt} \ [ \ 75 \ ] \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} · \tan \theta \ + \ H · \sec^2 \theta · \frac{d \theta}{dt} \ \ = \ \ 0 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} · \frac{75}{H} \ \ = \  \ -H · \left(\frac{L}{H} \right)^2 · \frac{d \theta}{dt} $$
$$  \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d \theta}{dt} \ \ = \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} · \frac{75}{H} · \left(-\frac{1}{H} \right) · \left(\frac{H}{L} \right)^2 \ \ = \ \ - \frac{dH}{dt} ·  \frac{75}{L^2}  \ \ .  $$

It works out that we don't need to know a value for $ \ H \ $ at all.  The rate at which the horizontal position is changing is $ \ \frac{dH}{dt} \ = \ +4 \ $ ft./sec. at the time when $ \ L \ = \ 250 \ $ feet, so we find that
$$ \frac{d \theta}{dt} \ \ = \ \  - (+4 \ \text{ft./sec.}) ·  \frac{75 \ \text{ft.}}{250^2 \ \text{ft.}^2 } \ \ = \ \ -\frac{300}{250·250} \ \frac{\text{(rad.)}}{\text{sec.}} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{3}{625} \ \text{rad./sec.}  \ \ .  $$

So we don't need to know a value for time $ \ t \  $ either.

The "problem" with using the cosine function here is that *neither* of the quantities in the ratio is constant (as **John Omielan** notes), so *everything* needs to be differentiated:

$$ L · \cos \theta \ \ = \ \ H \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d}{dt} \ [ \ L · \cos \theta \ ] \ \ = \ \ \frac{d}{dt} \ [ \ H \ ] $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dL}{dt} · \cos \theta \ + \ L · (-\sin \theta) · \frac{d \theta}{dt} \ \ = \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ 1 \ ]} $$

We need to use the "Pythagorean" relation $ \ H^2 \ = \ L^2 - 75^2 \ \  $ to "clear away" a certain factor, so that we can again avoid dealing with the value of $ \ t \ $ .  Differentiating this equation implicitly produces
$ \ 2·H·\frac{dH}{dt}   \ = \   2·L·\frac{dL}{dt} - 0 \ \Rightarrow \  \frac{dL}{dt}   \ = \   \frac{H}{L}·\frac{dH}{dt} \ \ . $  Equation $ \ \mathbf{1} \ $ can then be written as
$$  \left[ \ \frac{H}{L}·\frac{dH}{dt} \ \right] · \frac{H}{L} \ + \ L · \left(-\frac{75}{L} \right) · \frac{d \theta}{dt} \ \ = \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} · \left( \ 1 \ - \ \frac{H^2}{L^2} \ \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} · \left( \frac{L^2 \ - \ H^2}{L^2} \ \right) \ \ = \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} · \left( \frac{75^2}{L^2} \ \right) \ \ = \ \ -75 · \frac{d \theta}{dt} $$
$$  \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d \theta}{dt} \ \ = \ \ \frac{dH}{dt} · \left( -\frac{75}{L^2} \ \right) \ \ = \ \ - (+4) ·  \frac{75}{250^2}  \ \ ,  $$

yielding the same result as before after inserting the given simultaneous values of $ \ \frac{dH}{dt} \ $ and $ \ L \ \ . $